# no intellisense documentation for jsdocs

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense, jsdoc, web-essentials

I'm using VS2013, Web Essentials 2013 for Update 4, and ReSharper 8.2 C# Edition. I was under the impression that jsdocs should show up for methods, but it's not appearing. Any ideas why this would be the case?

[image: no-jsdoc]